# What is obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Razor folder?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I have a .net core 2.1 project, all run ok...
After add a NuGet dependency, and ricomplied
on obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.1 folder is create a new folder named "Razor" with inside a View strucure with files like this... Default.g.cshtml.cs

Some of this many errors occour.

Is it possible to do not create this folder?

Answer (score 0):

Razor used to be a separate project but was merged to .NET core.   You can see the source code for it here.  https://github.com/aspnet/Razor

Because Razor is a dependency as part of your .NET core project it will be included in your compiled code's output.